# How to add a private registry for image lookups in openshift

Tags: docker, openshift

I have a private registry at the url `registry.lab.example.com` where I can push images to from my master node in ocp cluster. When I go about launching a new app referring an image from this private registry, the lookup fails with a error message that the image is not found.

```
oc new-app --docker-image=registry.lab.example.com/openshift/nginx
```

My private registry is not even polled to look for the images and that'y why the deployment fails. Is there a way I can add this private registry in the list of **to be searched repositories** when docker tries to find an image?

Comment: Does private registry uses TLS? if not then add the entry in /etc/containers/registries.conf

Answer (score 0):

There's --add-registry option for docker daemon in RHEL's docker branch (see [registry-externally-accessible](https://blog.openshift.com/remotely-push-pull-container-images-openshift/), check if it's fit to your environment). In addition, you can configure the registry a primary docker source (see [pull-through-cache](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/)).